# ActiveRecord find parent records that have a specific subset of children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I've got the following associations:

Link

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :link_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :link_tags
end
```

LinkTag

```
class LinkTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Tag

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_tags, dependent: :destroy
end
```

On the Link index page, i've got some search controls. One of those search controls is a multi select box for tags. I am trying to come up with the most efficient active record query for finding all links with an exact subset of tags.

For example, I've got:

**Link1** has **TagA**, **TagB**, **TagC**

If I select TagA, and TagB in the search control, it will include this record. If I select TagA, TagB, TagC, and TagD it will NOT include this. Typically one would just use an IN clause to find any links that include those tags. In this case, I need to find all links that include ALL tags. I've been at this for hours, it seems like its probably a simple query that i'm just missing.

Thanks

Comment: Show your current attemt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might solve it with a active record like this:

```
tag_ids = params[:tag_ids].reject(:blank?) # or however you receive your ids from frontend
links = Link.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).group('links.id').having("COUNT(tags.id) = #{tag_ids.length}")
```

What is happening here is that you join all the tags you want and then you count them in order to make sure they are all there.

Comment: I believe that will do the trick! I'm going to try it when I get home tonight, thanks so much for the reply!

Comment: Just wanted to report, this worked like a charm. Thanks again for the help!